# How could I force windows to handle my program first

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-vista

I developed a desktop program (C#) with the purpose to notice me every 30 minutes a message (a message box appear on topMost and the program icon on taskbar blinks), then the OK_klick event remove the property topMost and the counter restart from zero.

But sometimes:

- my form doesn't appear topMost, but other applications (generally Web pages) cover it (I bypassed this with flashing the icon on task bar)
- my application semms hasn't pryority on other process (for example a web page is loading) with the result the form appear at later time.

Is it possible to give to my app an higer priority in order to, whatever the system is doing, the form appear in time?

My app runs on Vista, DotNet4.0, language C#

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You cannot steal the focus away from the window that the user is interacting with.  Just stop doing this the wrong way, use NotifyIcon.

Comment: ok tks, I will modify my code with notifyIcon.